# passing object back and popping two view controllers

Tags: xcode

I started learning Objective C and programming late last year and I’m dealing with Core Data, so I need some help.

I’m trying to select an object in VC3 and pass it to VC1 when the ‘Select’ button is pressed. Once pressed then it pops back to VC1 and display the object in the cell. I don’t think I can use a segue, because I want to go back and not forward. Also, I'm not going back to the root view controller.

Everything else works with segues, protocols and delegates except this issue. I’ve tried delegates, but they don’t seem to work, perhaps because there’s a view controller in between them or something. However, I’m very new to programming so I could be wrong.
I would appreciate some help and guidance.

Comment: For this what i do is i send the reference of VC1 to VC2 and then from VC2 to VC3 before pushing to next VC and when the object is selected set the value of some object in VC1 by using the reference of VC1
If you show me your code i will post the exact code for it.

Comment: @ Muhammad Thanks for your help Muhammad. Unfortunately I don't have any code for this issue yet, hence the problem. However, I thought of another way of doing it, by eliminating the need to select from VC3 and use the editing control option with an image of a plus sign in the prototype cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way (ios6+)  to do this is with an unwind segue

You create one of these by defining a method that takes a single argument of a storyBoardSegue.

```
- (IBAction)unwindOnSelect:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

Add this method to the viewController you want to unwind to.

Then, in the storyboard scene you want to unwind from... CTRL-drag from your 'Select' button to the green 'exit' symbol in the bar at the bottom of the scene. The unwind segue should appear in the popup as an option. Select it. Your button will unwind you to that destination, and code in the unwind segue method will be executed.

The segue object holds a reference to both source and destination viewControllers, so that is how you can get the data from one to the other.

```
  - (void)unwindOnSelect:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

       self.myObject = segue.sourceViewController.myProperty;

}
```

You will probably get an error here, "no known instance method for selector "myProperty". One way round this is to `#include "viewController3"` at the top of VC1's .h or .m file. You may have to typecast as well:

```
       self.myObject = [(ViewController1*)segue.sourceViewController myProperty];
```

Another way is a bit of indirection:

```
if ([segue.sourceViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(myProperty)]) {
    self.myObject = [segue.sourceViewController performSelector:@selector(myProperty)];
     }
```

This has the benefit that you do not have to `#include "viewController3"`, so you are a bit more decoupled, a bit more Objectified.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the segue unwind method